# undefined method `map' error on should create model test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, view, functional-testing

**app/controllers/products_controller.rb:**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

    # GET /products
    # GET /products.json
    def index
        #@products = Product.all
        @products = Product.all
        if params[:search]
            @products = Product.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
        else
            @products = Product.all.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
        end

        if session[:cart] then
            @cart = session[:cart]
        else
            @cart = {}
        end

    end

    # GET /products/1
    # GET /products/1.json
    def show
    end

    # GET /products/new
    def new
        if current_user.admin?
            #@product = Product.new
            @product = Product.new
            @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
        end
    end

    # GET /products/1/edit
    def edit
        if current_user.admin?
             @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
        end
    end

    # POST /products
    # POST /products.json
    def create
        if current_user.admin?
            @product = Product.new(product_params)
            @product.category_id = params[:category_id]

            respond_to do |format|
                if @product.save
                format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
                else
                format.html { render :new }
                format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                end
            end
        end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /products/1
    # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
    def update
        if current_user.admin?
            @product.category_id = params[:category_id]
            respond_to do |format|
                if @product.update(product_params)
                format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
                else
                format.html { render :edit }
                format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                end
            end
        end
    end

    # DELETE /products/1
    # DELETE /products/1.json
    def destroy
        if current_user.admin?
            @product.destroy
            respond_to do |format|
                format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
                format.json { head :no_content }
            end
        end
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
        params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :photo, :price, :category, :subcategory)
    end
end
```

**app/views/products/new.html.erb:**

```
<h1>New Product</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>
```

**app/views/products/_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for(@product, multipart: true) do |f| %>
  <% if @product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :price, :step => "0.01" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br>
    <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Select one!") %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My test in **test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:**

```
  test "should create product" do
    sign_in users(:admin)
    assert_difference('Product.count') do
      post :create, product: { category_id: @product.category, description: @product.description, photo_content_type: @product.photo_content_type, photo_file_name: @product.photo_file_name, photo_file_size: @product.photo_file_size, photo_updated_at: @product.photo_updated_at, price: @product.price, title: @product.title }
    end

    assert_redirected_to product_path(assigns(:product))
  end

Causing this error:

Finished in 0.816541s, 24.4936 runs/s, 35.5157 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_create_product:
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
    app/views/products/_form.html.erb:32:in `block in _app_views_products__form_html_erb__4489093195482743578_70189257075560'
    app/views/products/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_products__form_html_erb__4489093195482743578_70189257075560'
    app/views/products/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_products_new_html_erb__3438187527367239596_70189257283820'
    app/controllers/products_controller.rb:57:in `block (2 levels) in create'
    app/controllers/products_controller.rb:52:in `create'
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:28:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'

20 runs, 29 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

I'm running my tests with `rake test:functionals`. The other tests are fine but only this test is problematic.

There is even no any method named `map` in **app/views/products/_form.html.erb:**. So I don't have any idea for cause of this error.

If you want to look to the whole project: https://github.com/mertyildiran/SCOR

**CHANGES:**

According to answers:

In form I made this change: `<%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>`

In products controller: `params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :photo, :price, :category_id)`

And new version of test:

```
  test "should create product" do
    sign_in users(:admin)
    image = fixture_file_upload "../../public/assets/products/1/original/" + @product.photo_file_name
    puts image.inspect
    assert_difference('Product.count') do
      post :create, product: { category_id: @product.category, description: @product.description, photo: image, price: @product.price, title: @product.title }
    end

    assert_redirected_to product_path(assigns(:product))
  end
```

We get rid of error but Failure persist, stdout:

```
# Running:

.......#<Rack::Test::UploadedFile:0x007f5a1894fdf8 @content_type=nil, @original_filename="ra_unisex_tshirt_x1000_fafafa-ca443f4786_front-c_235_200_225_294-bg_f8f8f8_(7).jpg", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/ra_unisex_tshirt_x1000_fafafa-ca443f4786_front-c_235_200_225_294-bg_f8f8f8_(7).jpg20160515-31919-1j7oypa>>
F............

Finished in 0.800235s, 24.9926 runs/s, 37.4890 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_create_product [/home/mertyildiran/Documents/SCOR/test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:25]:
"Product.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 3
  Actual: 2

20 runs, 30 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

**Validation Failure Cause:**

```
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2>2 errors prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>Photo content type is invalid</li>
    <li>Photo is invalid</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Fixed with this `image.content_type = @product.photo_content_type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `post :create, product: ...` in your test a validation is failing which causes the new view to be rendered.

The `new` view then causes an error by calling `options_for_select(@categories)` but `@categories` is not defined - in other words `nil`. `options_for_select` expects the argument to be an array and calls `.map` on `nil`.

Thats not the only problem - you are not nesting the input properly either.

```
<%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Select one!") %>
```

Would end up in `params[:category_id]` not `params[:product][:category_id]`.

Instead what you want to do is use `collection_select` and bind it to the model:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :category_id %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>
```

You should also ensure that you are whitelisting the correct param - and if you have a hard time keeping track of them make sure you test it as well!

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :photo, :price, :category_id, :subcategory)
end
```

If you want to debug exactly what attribute causes the validation failure there are a few options:

- `assigns(:product)` will give you the `@product` instance variable from your controller. `assert_equals(@product.errors.full_messages, [])` gives you a list. You have to call the controller action first!
- You can do `assert_equals(@response.body, '')` to get a dump of the page HTML. You have to call the controller action first!
- Keep a tab on the logs with `$ tail -f logs/test.log`

Comment: Your validations are most likely failing due to the fact that the model `validates_attachment_presence :photo` but your controller does not whitelist the needed params.

Comment: I updated the question. Please take a look. I think simulating the image upload is the problem so please help me about this part also.

Comment: Added some info on how to debug it - but I think its pretty simple - the content type is of the uploaded file is nil. You might want to make sure the that the file path points to an actual image on disk (like a fixture in your /test) directory. Also you don't want to take the content type from the params passed by the user! Thats just asking for malicious users to spoof the content type.

Comment: Thx! I found the reason with `@response.body`. But I don't know how to fix. Could you take look to the question again. I updated.

Comment: I fixed with this: `image.content_type = @product.photo_content_type` Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thats not a very good solution - paperclip should be figuring out the mime type by looking at the file. Your letting the user tell the server exactly what type to treat the file as! This opens the door to XSS and script execution attacks. You should pay extra attention to this because of the recent ImageMagic vulnerabilities that have been widely exploited. https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: No I'm doing it in tests not the actual controller. @product is coming from fixtures.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace it appears that the validation failed when trying to save the `@product` and the controller wants to render the `new` template. But you don't have the `@categories` variable defined for this scenario, that is probably where the `map` call for `nil` is getting from.

So, probably you should do both of the following:

- add the `@categories` array to the failed save part of your `create` and `update` actions in your controller so that the failed-save scenario works ok
- fix the test code so that the validations do not fail when creating the product.

Comment: Could you say why the validations fail? Still I don't know how to fix.

Comment: I updated the question. Please take a look. I think simulating the image upload is the problem so please help me about this part also.